# Insert record from one data extension to another data extension in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I would like to know whether it is possible to insert records to a data extension from another data extension in Journey builder. The DE1 will have unique customer information. DE2 will have duplicated customer information with some delivery status details. DE2 will have some purge logic to delete old records. Would this be possible in Journey builder?

Comment: I would consider using a send log for this: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000333925&language=en_US

Comment: @LukasLunow, Sorry I am not familiar with Send log DE. From the documentation, it seems the data is inserted during each send. But we need to insert user data prior to sending message with status not send and later consume the records to process delivery.